# VS Code Remote Development Errors

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

I am connected to my company's VPN on my Windows 10 desktop and uses VS Code for my development. I wanted to use VS Code Remote Development so that I can connect to my remote company development server and autosave my files directly on the server. I have installed VS Code Remote Development package and this is my SSH config.

```
  Host my.company.server
  HostName 10.XXX.XXX.XX6
  User root
  IdentityFile C:\Users\My_User\Documents\Company\company_key.pem
```

However, when connect VS Code to the remote server, VS Code shows that I am connected but I am getting the errors below and cannot view the remote directory.

```
Unable to write to Folder Settings because no resource is provided.
Could not fetch remote environment.
Failed to connect to the remote extension host server
(Error: Websocket close with status code 1006)
```

I tried connecting to the remote server using WinSCP and that works fine. I also used PowerShell to login using the below command and that works fine too.

```
ssh -i C:\Users\My_User\Documents\Company\company_key.pem root@10.XXX.XXX.XX6
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any VS Code gurus can assist me with this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

VSCode was attempting to download and install several components on that remote machine, which probably was blocked by the machine administrators in your company (as downloading from an external resource is commonly seen as a security risk on an internal machine).

You should carefully review the information security policies of the company before making any violation. And then discuss with your manager to see if VSCode Remote should be used or not.